# Recall sheet name from a cell in sheet 1 to recall data from a sheet with a custom name

Tags: google-sheets

Im trying to make a google sheet were people can enter in data on their own sheet and have the data recall on the main sheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCPfI.png)

Basically everyone will have their own sheet with there name on it and they will enter their name on the main sheet. On main sheet it will call all the data from their sheet. People will enter their name on line 2. I want a code that will take name and find the sheet with their name and call in all the data. I tried using =B2!B3 but google sheets thinks I'm trying to find sheet "B2" and not the name in cell B2. how do I get it to call in the name from cell B2

Answer (score 0):

use `INDIRECT`:

```
=INDIRECT(B2&"!"&B3)
```

B2 being the sheet name and B3 = cell or range

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ft2aM00KR4S4r1-yKUjA_2coV9oAY0hArmhovho2owM/copy)

Comment: Im getting a error saying "Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings." but I assume that its more on my end

Comment: @JoshuaNagle pls examine the included spreadsheet